# Send Twitter DM with attached photo, in Python

Tags: python, twitter, raspberry-pi, tweepy

I'm trying to send a DM from a Raspberry Pi connected to the internet to a specific user, but I also want to attach a photo to said DM. Is this possible with tweepy? If so, how do you recommend me to do this?
I have read the documentation, and haven't found a single thing relating DMs with photos.
If tweepy can't do this, is there any other library that can?
Thank you.